# _CleanGetCurrentAndPriorFileWrites Failing on Teamcity

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, teamcity, continuous-deployment

I have an azure web worker that I am trying to deploy via teamcity. Deploying other web workers  projects are no problem on the build server. The project deploys fine from within visual studio. When I try to deploy the project in team city I get the error message:

```
[14:32:25][Web.UI.Azure\Web.UI.Azure.ccproj.teamcity] _CleanGetCurrentAndPriorFileWrites
[14:32:25]  [_CleanGetCurrentAndPriorFileWrites] FindUnderPath
[14:32:25]    [FindUnderPath] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(4017, 5): error MSB3541: Files has invalid value "csx\Release\**\__entrypoint.txt". Illegal characters in path.
[14:32:25][Web.UI.Azure\Web.UI.Azure.ccproj.teamcity] Project Web.UI.Azure\Web.UI.Azure.ccproj.teamcity failed.
```

I have tried to identify the difference between the projects and can't see an relevant differences.

What might cause the build process to fail in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fault came down to this line in the visual studio project:

```
<Content Include="**\*.html" />
```

One of the file paths was 165 characters longs, shortening the file path fixed the problem. It doesn't explain why the deployment worked in Visual Studio and not on Team City, but at least it works everywhere now.